# How to convert decimal to time in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

In a certain table I'm querying, time is stored like this:

09:30 is stored as 9,3

14:25 is stored as 14,25

How can I, using SQL, convert 9,3 to 09:30 (hh:mm format)? 
So far, the only thing I could find in other questions are people who need to convert 9,5 to 09:30 (in my case, 9,5 means 09:50).

Right now, I'm using PHP to convert this. But my DB server is better than my application server. Since I need to get a lot of data, it would be better to solve this using SQL.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to SQL. Feel free to ask for more questions if you need to.

Comment: Are those stored as numbers or strings? What data type are you trying to end up with - '09:30' as a string? And would say 09:03 be stored as 9,03? (I'm resisting asking *why* these are store like this...)

Comment: They are stored as numbers, I want to end up with 09:30 as time and 9,03 means 09:03. Not sure why they are stored like this, I think the company that makes the ERP that creates and manages the data decided it was a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming those are numeric values, you can get the hour part with `trunc(your_column)` and the minutes part with `100 * mod(your_column, 1)`. That gives you two numbers; you can format those and concatenate them, again assuming you want a string result, e.g.:

```
to_char(trunc(your_column), 'FM00') ||':' || to_char(100 * mod(your_column, 1), 'FM00')
```

Or more simply, format the whole number as a single string in one step, by telling it to use a colon as the decimal separator (with anything as the group separator - that isn't used):

```
to_char(your_column, 'FM00D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=:,')
```

Demo with sample data in a CTE:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (time) as (
  select 9.3 from dual
  union all select 9.03 from dual
  union all select 14.25 from dual
)
-- actual query
select time,
  to_char(trunc(time), 'FM00') ||':' || to_char(100 * mod(time, 1), 'FM00') as new_time1,
  to_char(time, 'FM00D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=:,') as new_time2
from your_table;

      TIME NEW_TIME1 NEW_TIME2
---------- --------- ---------
       9.3 09:30     09:30    
      9.03 09:03     09:03    
     14.25 14:25     14:25
```

If you actually want an interval data type result then you can use the same split with trunc/mod but handle the two numbers differently:

```
select time,
  numtodsinterval(trunc(time), 'HOUR')
    + numtodsinterval(100 * mod(time, 1), 'MINUTE') as new_time
from your_table;

      TIME NEW_TIME           
---------- -------------------
       9.3 +00 09:30:00.000000
      9.03 +00 09:03:00.000000
     14.25 +00 14:25:00.000000
```

Or you can convert to that time on a nominal date if you prefer, e.g.:

```
date '2000-01-01'
  + trunc(your_column), 'HOUR')
  + numtodsinterval(100 * mod(your_column, 1), 'MINUTE')
```

At some point you'll run into problems if you have values that don't really represent valid times - for example, 9.60 or 25.3. Either of the queries above will handle that to some extent - at least, up to 99.99 for the first one - but won't necessarily give useful results. The string would give you '09:60' and '25:30', while the interval would give you '0 10:00:00' and '1 01:30:00', which is slightly more sensible perhaps. That's the danger of using an inappropriate data type though.

---

Preserving a comment from @BobJarvis, if you actually want a date data type result then you can convert the number to a string without any separator and then convert from that to a date:

```
to_date(to_char(your_column, '00V00'), 'HH24MI')
```

which will give you that time on the first day of the current month. However, that *will* error with 9.60 or 25.3.

Comment: Thanks. That's really what I needed.

Comment: @LucasLisboa - I added a simpler method *8-)

Comment: I'd suggest not even fiddling with the decimal point or separators. TO_DATE is perfectly happy with a format of `'HH24MI`, and TO_CHAR can convert a number without putting in a decimal point by using the `'V'` format character for an assumed decimal point, which leads you to `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TIMEVAL, '00V00'), 'HH24MI')`, and Bob (not me, some other guy) is your parental male sibling. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis - the OP accepted as a string result so I still think that's what they want; but as I included an interval result anyway it's only fair to include a date version - in which case your approach is simpler than the date+interval one I hinted at, or converting to a string with colon and then to a date. Thanks.